# "Failed to create COM object `hMailServer.Application'", although Everyone has launch and activation DCOM permissions

Tags: php, email-server, windows-server-2012-r2, dcom, plesk

In a Windows Server 2012 R2 Datacenter environment with IIS 8.5.9600.16384, Plesk 12.5.30 Update #24 and hMailServer 5.6.4-B2283 I'm trying to install the web interface PHPWebAdmin that ships with hMailServer to allow the users to access their mail account from everywhere. hMailServer has been connected with SQL Server 2012 R2, successfully.

I followed [this](https://www.hmailserver.com/documentation/latest/?page=howto_install_phpwebadmin) official tutorial. I configured Plesk to use PHP 5.2.17 and I've set `register_globals` and `display_errors` to off and set `com.allow_dcom = true`.

To make sure I got permission to access the COM interface of hMailServer from PHPWebAdmin I followed [this](https://www.hmailserver.com/documentation/latest/?page=howto_dcom_permissions) instructions, too. However, for test purposes I enabled full access of everything for `Everyone`!

Unfortunately, I still receive this error message when trying to access PHPWebAdmin in my browser:

```
Failed to create COM object `hMailServer.Application': Access is denied. 
This problem is often caused by DCOM permissions not being set.
```

Does anybody know a solution to this?

**EDIT**: I wrote a little VBS code file and executed it locally to see if the COM object can be accessed, successfully:

```
Dim app
Set app = CreateObject("hMailServer.Application")
```

This worked.

Comment: Could your please share are you going to integrate hMailServer with Plesk? As I know Plesk doesn't support hMailServer since Plesk 10.4.

Comment: @OlegNeumyvakin You are right, I did not integrate hMailServer into Plesk and I'm not going to, since I could use PHPWebAdmin to allow my users to manage the mail account. However, I configured the domain and webspace for PHPWebAdmin in Plesk. Btw, MailEnable is still installed, but I disabled all services, entirely. hMailServer is working properly.